# modify paypal sandbox test site store name and image logo

Tags: asp.net, paypal, integration, sandbox

hi is it possible to modify paypal sandbox test store name and image logo when customer is redirected to the paypal site. I am using express checkout workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [PayPal X Developer Network: How do I change the name of my test app...](https://www.x.com/thread/40529) thread regarding this issue.